# Multipart Web API Action in Owin Self Host Inconsistency

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, mono, multipartform-data, owin

I've have a self hosted owin web api application and it has a action that takes multipart/form-data as saves to content directory in the server (which in later will be sent to user as http link to image files, is this a good way to do so?). Here is the controller code:

```
        [HttpPost]
    public async Task<object> Post()
    {
        if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent("form-data"))
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType));
        }

        string rootFolder = Path.Combine("Content");
        var provider = new NamedMultipartFormDataStreamProvider(rootFolder);

        try
        {
            //read the form data
            await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);

            foreach (MultipartFileData file in provider.FileData)
            {
                Trace.WriteLine(file.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName);
                Trace.WriteLine("Saving to server... " + file.LocalFileName);

            }

            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        }
        catch (System.Exception e)
        {
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, e);
        }

    }
```

It works well in Windows 8.1 in Visual Studio 2013. However, it doesn't work and gives UnsupportedMediaType exception as if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent("form-data")) statement fails. I've made the both the requests from Google Chrome. Here is the comparision of two POST requests.

Windows 8.1 POST request that succeeds

```
Remote Address:[::1]:2004
Request URL:http://localhost:2004/api/stories
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK
Request Headersview source
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:311070
Content-Type:multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryrVbEaAZmQGuJBNEb
Host:localhost:2004
Origin:http://localhost:2004
Referer:http://localhost:2004/api/help
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.103 Safari/537.36
Request Payload
------WebKitFormBoundaryrVbEaAZmQGuJBNEb
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="caption"

Life
------WebKitFormBoundaryrVbEaAZmQGuJBNEb
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="image1"; filename="Primate.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg


------WebKitFormBoundaryrVbEaAZmQGuJBNEb--
Response Headersview source
Content-Length:0
Date:Mon, 08 Sep 2014 21:24:26 GMT
Server:Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
```

POST that fails in Mono JIT compiler version 3.8.0

```
Remote Address:127.0.0.1:2004
Request URL:http://localhost:2004/api/stories
Request Method:POST
Status Code:415 Unsupported Media Type
Request Headersview source
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:681954
Content-Type:multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryW4NqTv782jlZ186F
Host:localhost:2004
Origin:http://localhost:2004
Referer:http://localhost:2004/api/help
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.94 Safari/537.36
Request Payload
------WebKitFormBoundaryW4NqTv782jlZ186F
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="caption"

This is Test Image Caption
------WebKitFormBoundaryW4NqTv782jlZ186F
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="image1"; filename="1407231597673.png"
Content-Type: image/png


------WebKitFormBoundaryW4NqTv782jlZ186F--
Response Headersview source
Content-Length:0
Date:Mon, 08 Sep 2014 23:39:11 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=15,max=100
Server:Mono-HTTPAPI/1.0
```

How should I fix this?

Regards

Edit

If I comment the IsMimeMultipartContent("form-data") part it gives me follow error.

```
ExceptionMessage: "Invalid 'HttpContent' instance provided.
It does not have a  content-type header value.
'HttpContent' instances must have a content-type header starting with 'multipart/'. Parameter name: content",
ExceptionType: "System.ArgumentException",
```

If anyone is wondering `NamedMultipartFormDataStreamProvider` used is https://github.com/devcurry/webapi-file-upload/blob/master/MultipleFileUpload/Controllers/NamedMultipartFormDataStreamProvider.cs

Edit 2:

Seems to be Mono bug and it goes inside the following if.

```
  if (Request.Content.Headers.ContentType == null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("header is null");
        }
```

This might be Mono bug where if Request.Content.Headers.ContentType is never initialized and is always null. While debugging through, at same point Request.Content.Headers.ContentType is initialized properly in Windows but never in Mono.

https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=22764